# How to enable email alerts for Firebase crash reports

Tags: email, firebase, firebase-console, firebase-crash-reporting

In the [Firebase crash reporting guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/), there is a list of *key capabilities* where it lists one capability as:

> Enable email alerts to receive frequent updates when new crashes are uncovered or regressions are detected.

I would like to activate that feature, but I can't seem to find the way of doing so. I found two things related in the console:

1. If I navigate to Settings -> Service Accounts -> Crash Reporting, I can see some links to the docs.
2. If i click on the three dot next to my picture in the upper right corner of the console, there are the *users settings*, in which I can select *Alert subscriptions*. I select my app and I can see all *email* check-boxes checked

I still don't receive anything when a new bug or regression is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just received an email for a test I did *yesterday*. Basically, the reports appear in the console in a matter of minutes, but it took almost 20 hours to get the email. I guess the emails are sent on a daily basis containing the reports of the day before. Note that I did not change anything in the settings in that project, meaning the emails were enabled by default.